# Detecting a page refresh in Safari on iOS

Tags: refresh

Is it possible in mobile safari to get notified when the user clicks on refresh button. I want to prevent users from accidentally leaving the page as they might have some unsaved data on the page. I have a code that shows a prompt in safari desktop but for touch safari it just does not show anything and refreshes the page